# Android: Show number data

Tags: android, listview, charts, numbers

In my app, I have a weight - diary. I can add the current weight to my database but I don´t know what is the best way to show it to the user. In a ListView seems not very user-friendly for me, and I haven´t found a good and beautiful chart for Android.

How can I show the user the weight-data in a user-friendly way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Charting Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307873/android-charting-library)

Comment: You can use use some different type of chart for it. look some example here. http://www.achartengine.org/ or http://danielkvist.net/code/piechart-with-achartengine-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Android library called aChartEngine. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) is a link. You can use that to easily create nice representations for lots of numbers and it provides you a bunch of different ways to do it. This should be exactly what you're looking for.